# why does the .bind() not work outside the .ready() function?

Tags: jquery

On click of a button I am showing an alert message. Below is the code that I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickHere").bind("click",function(){
        alert('clicked');
     });
 //});
 </script>
```

As the .ready() line is commented, when I click on the button the alert message is not thrown, but if I uncomment those lines the the alert is thrown. Shouldn't the alert message be shown in both the cases as I have added binding to the button on 'click' event?

Comment: Question: is `<foo id="clickHere">` before or after the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Your question is pretty much the poster child of why "ready" is important.

Comment: I had added the <input>tag after the script..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `.ready()` function is a jquery callback shortcut, only triggering once the DOM (html) has been loaded into the browser.  If you bind your function outside of the ready, there's a pretty good chance that DOM element won't be loaded yet, and therefore won't bind properly.

You could try moving your script to the bottom of your doc, right before the closing body tags, which would cause it to load after your other DOM elements, but as a standard practice, I usually don't bind DOM elements until the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

because at the time the javascript block is parsed, the DOM is not ready, hence the element you reference does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM needs to be ready to be manipulated by JavaScript before it can have items applied to it.

[Try reading the documentation as to why it is necessary.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the button has already been created in the DOM. If your code is in the head of the page this wouldn't have occurred, but if it was before the closing body tag it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the functionality to set an event handler on an element when the DOM is not ready to be parsed, I believe you can use the 'on' method where you can "attach an event handler function for one or more events on elements now and in the future".

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

In a very loose sense, think of $('document').ready() in the same way you would think of the Main() method in other programming languages.